# What is the interpretation of a Kernel $K(x,y)$ in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

Going over the Contraction mappings and integral equation section in kolmogorov's Real Analysis book Section 8.3 I realized I do not totally understand the role of a Kernel. The definition of it is not really clear.

This probably if a very broad question but, would it be possible to make it really clear on how to interpret this notion of Kernel specifically for real analysis?

In the book the first time we encounter this term is in the Fredholm equation which is an integral of the form

$$f(x)=\lambda \int_a^b K(x,y)f(y)dy +\phi (x),$$

It involves 2 functions $K$ and $\phi$ an unknown function $f$ and an arbitrary parameter $\lambda$. The function $K$ is called the Kernel of the equation and, the equation is said to be homogenous if $\phi=0$. This is it, but, it is not very clear. Do we always need an integral equation to have a kernel? Is there a geometrical interpretation that can make it more clear? Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Geometrically, it's as if you're projecting $f$ onto $K$,i.e. taking an inner product on $L^2$ of $f$ and $K$.

Comment: a kernel play the same role as an uncountable dimensional matrix, that is, and integral of the form $g(y):=\int K(x,y) f(x)dx$ is like "matrix multiplication" on uncountable dimensions, there $\int K$ play the role of the matrix, $f$ the role of a vector, and $g$ is the result